# How to derive the $W_1$ Wasserstein distance written with the quantile functions (i.e. with inverse cumulative distribution functions)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, optimal-transport, wasserstein

**INTRODUCTION.** Either downloading the slides on Optimal Transport (OT) from the [Marco Cuturi website](https://marcocuturi.net/index.html) (go to section "Teaching ENSAE --> [OT](https://marcocuturi.net/ot.html) --> Optimal Transport (Spring 2023)
[slides]" and click on "slides"), or just watching his lectures on YouTube ([Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6iR1E6t1MMQ), [Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R49Xb9eAUBA) and [Part 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZHumKEhgtA&t=527s)), Dr. Cuturi shows the following:

1. the Monge Problem (pag. 157/432),
2. the Primal form of the Kantorovich problem (pag. 168/432),
3. the Dual form of the Kantorovich problem (pag. 170/432),
4. the definition of the Wasserstein Distance (pag. 192/432),
5. the Semi-Dual form of the Wasserstein Distance (pag. 192/432),
6. the $W_1$ Wasserstein Distance written using the inverse cumulative distribution functions (pag. 243/432, or [Part 3 at minute 8:25](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZHumKEhgtA&t=505s))

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**QUESTION.** **How can I derive the object "6. the $W_1$ Wasserstein Distance written using the inverse cumulative distribution functions (pag. 243/432)" from either object 1., or 2., or 3., or 4., or 5.?**

**In other words, where does the object "6. the $W_1$ Wasserstein Distance written using the inverse cumulative distribution functions (pag. 243/432)" come from?**

Any suggestion is welcome!